# C# accessing HTTPS Files

Tags: c#, https

I have figured out(by inspecting both the website its-self and the response form the website when using my C# application) that the website in question does not use the form's nor cookies to do the secure connections so I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to potentially use the SSL certificate or the website headers(which by all accounts I think do have a cookie in them), to allow the log-in and then download of a certain file.

Could I get code examples or links to ways to use the headers to log-in to a site is what I am asking, I have all the necessary credentials just not the extensive knowledge to use them.

Thanks a bunch.

```
      public void downloadStuff()
    {
        string formUrl = "https://secure.website.co.nz/extension/Login.aspx";
        string formParams = string.Format("ctl00_main_Login1_UserName={0}&ctl00_main_Login1_Password={1}", "*********", "************");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        string pageSource;
        string getUrl = "https://secure.website.co.nz/extension/Downloader.axd?x=stock-all";
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            WebClient exeed = new WebClient();
            exeed.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"https://secure.website.co.nz/extension/Downloader.axd?x=stock-all"), "test.txt");
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Note: This question was also put up because if what I have done is correct, I would not know how to use a cookie to download a file. Potentially example code of how to capture and use a cookie and or a header would be the best option. 
Thanks, This was an edit!

Comment: Can you possibly show us your code?

Comment: Sure, although the code that I used to figure out only the header is available may have been deleted.